# Getting default slider thumb location value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

How do you get the default/current value of the slider thumb location?

My program would display (from a popup message box) a number from a range of numbers, e.g. 1 to 100, by moving the slider to a position and executing the popup via a button.

The program does show correct results when I move the slider thumb and pressing the button (e.g. move the the thumb to the estimated location of #30 and the prompt shows 30).

Though I discovered a "bug" when I pressed the button before even moving the slider thumb in where instead of showing the resulting number it prompted 0. (e.g. like starting the program then pressing the button, given the current thumb location is at the estimate location of #50, resulted in an output of 0 instead of 50).

I did use *slider.value* thinking that it will get the (default)number of the slider thumb but to no avail. Also declaring the default value in the code (e.g. x = 50) is an unacceptable attempt.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

for example you display your value on label. In my case I display a value of `slider.value` and `x` value. Its look like this:

for `slider.value`:

`_label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", _slider.value];`

and for `x =`

`_label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x];`